# Changing padding based on form input

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying (it's not working) to pad an element based on a form input. If the input is more than one integer it should change the padding. This is my script right now.

```
function pad() {
if ($('input[name=amount]').val().length > 1) {
$('ibet').css('margin-left', '6px');
} else {
$('ibet').css('margin-left', '');
}
}
```

The HTML is

```
<p id = "ibet">$</p>
```

The form triggering the function

```
<input id='inpamount' type="text" name="amount" value="2.00" onkeyup="pad();validatemin()">
```

And the CSS for this HTML is

```
#ibet {
margin: 0px;
font-family: GothamBook,Helvetica,sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 28px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 11px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: so what is the problem? is it not working?

Comment: Nope :*( Unfortunately not

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are targeting an element id, you need `#`

```
$('#ibet').css('margin-left', '6px');
```

```js
function pad() {
  if ($('input[name=amount]').val().length > 1) {
    $('#ibet').css('margin-left', '6px');
  } else {
    $('#ibet').css('margin-left', '');
  }
}
```

```css
#ibet {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: GothamBook, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="ibet">$</p>

<input id='inpamount' type="text" name="amount" value="2.00" onkeyup="pad();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `#ibet` not `ibet` as a selector when selecting an ID. You can use the `keyup()` function to detect keystrokes, and call your `pad()` method.

Below is a snippet example. I added an `#ibet div`, and gave it some extra css attributes for clarity.

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $('input[name=amount]').keyup(function() {
    pad($(this));
  });
 function pad(selector) {
    if (selector.val().length > 1) {
      $('#ibet').html('LENGTH > 1<br />MARGIN: 6px');
      $('#ibet').css('margin-left', '6px');
    } else {
      $('#ibet').html('LENGTH <= 1<br />MARGIN: 0px');
      $('#ibet').css('margin-left', '');
    }
  }
 
});
```

```css
#ibet {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: GothamBook, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 11px;
 width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inpamount' type="text" name="amount" value="" onkeyup="pad();validatemin()">
<br /><br />
<div id="ibet"></div>
```